# Wanted to query remote PCs uptime with powershell

Tags: powershell, wmic

I wanting to query machines uptime and decided to try this via powershell but I am struggling to get it to work. Here's what I've done so far:

```
   function Get-PCUptime {

        param (
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            [String]$computer  = (Read-Host "Enter a computer name")
        )


        $lastboottime = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Credential Administrator -comp $computer)
        $sysuptime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($lastboottime.LastBootUpTime)

        if ($lastboottime -ne $NULL){
            Write-Host “System($computer) is Uptime since : ” $sysuptime.days “days” $sysuptime.hours `
            “hours” $sysuptime.minutes “minutes” $sysuptime.seconds “seconds” -Foregroundcolor Gray;
        } 
    }
```

I can't seem to make it work as I am wanting to convert it to days, hours, minutes, etc.

This is the error I receive:

> Exception calling "ToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: dmtfDate"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ConvertToDateTime` method on `Win32_OperatingSystem`

```
function Get-PCUptime {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   HelpMessage="Enter a Computer Name"
        )]
        [String]$computer
    )

    $OS = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Credential Administrator -comp $computer)
    $sysuptime = (Get-Date) – ($OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime))

    if ($OS -ne $NULL){
        Write-Host “System($computer) is Uptime since : ” $sysuptime.days “days” $sysuptime.hours `
        “hours” $sysuptime.minutes “minutes” $sysuptime.seconds “seconds” -Foregroundcolor Gray;
    } 
}
```